# spring mvc annotation validation

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, validation, annotations

I have a form that looks like this

```
public class ValidationForm {
  private Person person;
  @Size(min=1,max=10,message="out of range")
  private String test;
  //other stuff
```

My validation controller is like this

```
public void processForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("validateForm") ValidationForm vform, 
  BindingResult result){
```

My Person class is like this

```
public class Person {
private String id;
@Size(min=1, max=35, message="Enter less than 35 Charercters")
private String firstName;
@Size(min=1, max=35, message="Enter less than 35 Charercters")
private String lastName;
```

if firstname or lastname is empty in my jsp page, there is no validation error. but if test is empty then there is a validation error. What should i do to validate properties of object in the form. Right now only properties of the form are getting validated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I changed my validation form to

```
public class ValidationForm {
@Valid
private Person person;
@Size(min=1,max=10,message="out of range")
private String test;
```

and now it works

Comment: @user373201: can you get the message "out of range" from the properties file?